# Trigger an onBlur in react when a certain key is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple React input which triggers an action if key pressed is 'Enter' - it'll perform a network request later, but for now just triggers a log of state.

Here's the input:

```
<input onKeyDown={handleEnterPress} />
```

And here's the onKeyDown event, which is triggering successfully:

```
const handleEnterPress = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {

        if (e.code === "Enter") {
            console.log(state);
        }
        
    }
```

However, at the moment, the input remains 'focused' when enter is pressed - when in reality, what I want to happen is the input to be unfocused, meaning the action is effectively 'complete' and no more editing is required.

I've been trying to search for a way to do this - but can't find anything. What would be the most effective and efficient way of me unfocusing the input upon 'enter' being pressed?

Comment: `e.target.blur()` or `document.activeElement.blur()`

Comment: I've figured it out - need to cast it as a HTMLElement as I'm using TypeScript. Thanks for the responses!